# How to add another page in appearance tab of admin panel?

Tags: customization, admin-menu

Currently I am working on Wordpress and I want to know can I add 1 more page in admin panel appearance menu so that it looks like this: ?

```
Appearance
  Themes
  Widgets
  Menus
  Editor
```

I want to add one more page after Editor like "Theme option".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use the add_theme_page() function. Basically, it's the same as adding any other settings page, but instead of add_options_page(), you use add_theme_page().

More info:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus